# Cassandra as input to Hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

Can anyone give me an example how can I (if possible) perform a MapReduce job over data from Cassandra queried using SELECT statement?

I'm new to Cassandra, and not very experienced with Hadoop, but I would like to know is it possible to run a job only on a subset of data, not on entire table.

Comment: You may be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583834/cassandra-and-mapreduce-minimal-setup-requirements

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm hopping for an example how to select data of interest as input to Hadoop job...